# faster alternative to 2N3904

Tags: transistors

Can anyone recommend a "general purpose" small-signal BJT NPN transistor that is similar in most regards to 2N3904, but has a higher fT? The 2N3904 has a fT around 300 MHz, but I'd like something in the 600 MHz or higher area. Ideally it'd be optimized for gain around 10 mA and relatively inexpensive. No surface mount components please--looking for something that can be breadboarded or dead bugged.

Comment: Digikey has a good search engine for this type of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PN3569](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Central-Semiconductor/PN3569/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2FWi8oN7VHZ91OkWLtOpsIygqo%3D) seems to be the only one with equal or greater than 600MHz fT and equal or greater max Ic on Mouser with the same package. The max E-B voltage is 5V instead of 6V like the 2N3904, if that matters to you.

Comment: I selected this as the better answer, as this part (at time of writing) is available at more vendors online (than the NTE161) and is roughly half the cost.

Answer (score 0):

NTE161 Silicon NPN transistor have fT 600MHz and have low Output Capacitance of about Cob:1.7pF. Emitter–Base Breakdown Voltage is about 3V